# What is the correct ENTRYPOINT for Asp.net Core RC2 Dockerfile

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

How do I start kestral on asp.net RC2 in a docker container?

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "kestrel"]
```

My app builds fine, but i get 
`C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Container command 'dnx' not found or does not exist..`

Is there another `dnx` command for RC ? Do I need to use `dotnet` somehow? I can get my app to run outside of docker by running `dotnet run .` works great.

Comment: There is no dnx at all for RC2. RC only works with dotnet. dnx is deprecated and won't be updated anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dnx` is for RC1. `dotnet` is for RC2 (and newer). Don't mix them up.

The entry point should be `dotnet run --project <project>`.

Comment: Thanks. My mind is still blown that I'm writing true ASP under Linux without mono.